# React: How to get setState to re-render my component after sorting an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app that is showing data in table form, and the user should be able to sort the data according to the different columns. My data is an array of objects.

I am using this sorting function that is taking the variable according to which to sort, and a boolean indicating the order of the sorting:

```
  function sortBy(variable, sortDescending) {
    setActivities(prev => prev.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[variable] > b[variable]) {
        return sortDescending ? -1 : 1;
      }
      else if (a[variable] < b[variable]) {
        return sortDescending ? 1 : -1;
      }
      else {
        return 0;
      }
    }));
    
   }
```

The function is working fine, however React refuses to update the child component which is showing the table. Apparently this is because React doesn't think sorting an array is a change.

I have tried a ton of things, including copying the array, pretending to edit the array with .map,  adding a state variable and changing that, etc. This is super frustrating :/ Anyone has an enlightening idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Array.sort` returns the same reference to the array, try to do this `[...Array.sort()]`. This will create a new array, which triggers the update.

Comment: Or `prev.slice().sort(...)`.

Comment: You have to update the reference of your array